# Dropbox migration(API v1 retired) iOS Objective c (Backup,restore)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud-api, dropbox-sdk

Friends please help me how to migrate dropbox v1 to v2.

My manager gives an old project to me, in this they have used sqlite database for store locally and Dropbox sdk to do backup the files.

But the Dropbox v1 is retired now. i'm in serious trouble now.

My manager is asking either do with dropbox or iCloud?

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

As Dropbox has made mandatory to use dropbox V2 September 2017, you will have to implement Dropbox V2 API's.

If the project is in objective-C changes are minimal. Instead of delegates which were used in V1, they have provided blocks to the developers. Blocks are really helpful in reducing code complexity as response is returned inside the block.

You can download Objective-C sdk from here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/objective-c

In my case, I had created Dropbox manager. So, instead of making complex changes, I created extension of my existing class and started to replace delegate with blocks provided in V2.

Regarding swift sdk of Dropbox, as far as I know, it is introduced officially by Dropbox in V2 only (I might be wrong here, because i never searched and saw for swift sdk of Dropbox before V2).

To download swift sdk of Dropbox V2, follow the link:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift